# Scheme Function - Odd-Number-Sum?

Tags: function, scheme, racket

I'm working on Racket in Scheme for a class and the problem is to create a recursive function that displays the sum of n odd numbers starting from 1. The program just keeps running and running and I can't understand why. Any help would be appreciated.
(ie if I call (odd-sum 2) I want it to evaluate 1 + 3 (first two odd numbers) and display 4)

```
(define (odd-sum n)
 (odd-sum-work (- (* 2 n) 1)))
(define (odd-sum-work n)
 (if (= n 1)
      1)
     (+ n (odd-sum-work (- n 2))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tiny bug where you have misplaced your parentheses:

```
(define (odd-sum-work n)
 (if (= n 1)
      1)
     (+ n (odd-sum-work (- n 2))))
```

should be

```
(define (odd-sum-work n)
 (if (= n 1)
      1
     (+ n (odd-sum-work (- n 2)))))
```

Reindenting your code in DrRacket, it reads

```
(define (odd-sum-work n)
    (if (= n 1) 
         1)
    (+ n (odd-sum-work (- n 2))))
```

which makes it more obvious that the conditional has no "else" branch — if `n` is 1, the `1` is evaluated but thrown away, and evaluation continues with a recursion that will never terminate.

("Reindent" is in the "Racket" menu. It has saved me from plenty of grief.)

Comment: Maybe you should add a check to make sure `n` is odd. Or use less than or equal in the conditional.

Comment: @Rptx Parameter validation doesn't really belong in a helper function, in my opinion. It's a better idea to define it locally to the "public" function.

Comment: you're write. But you didn't include the "public" function in your answer. Maybe just a note. OP may fix the parentheses and still get infinite loops after that. Maybe just add a note?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of sum the numbers from 0 to n (inclusive):

```
(define (sum-from-zero-to n)
  (if (= n 0)
      0
      (+ n (sum-from-zero-to (- n 1)))))

; > (sum-from-zero-to 3) ; 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 6
; 6
```

Let's look at the problem of summing even numbers (then you can change it to sum odd numbers).

We need a helper that computes the n'th even number:

```
(define (nth-even-number n)
  (* 2 n))

; > (nth-even-number 0)
; 0
; > (nth-even-number 1)
; 2
; > (nth-even-number 2)
; 4
```

Now it is simple to sum the even numbers (compare to `sum-from-zero-to`)

```
(define (sum-of-even-numbers n)
  (if (= n 0)
      0
      (+ (nth-even-number n)
         (sum-of-even-numbers (- n 1)))))

> (sum-of-even-numbers 3) ; 0 + 2 + 4 + 6 = 12
12
```